# bootstrap custom CSS build for datepicker only

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am making an angular application and I make use of the UI Bootstrap components build for Angular.js: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

I do only need Bootstrap css for the datepicker. Right now it's overriding all of my custom layout.

I tried making a custom build from the official Bootstrap website, but I don't really know which components are needed for the datepicker only.

Comment: What happened when you tried it? What happens when you click "Create a Build", select "Datepicker", download, and implement?

Comment: I have no problems with angular UI Bootstrap components. My problem is with the dependency being bootstrap css. It all works fine, but i won't want bootstrap changing my current layout on other views.

Answer (score 0):

I have a rather far fetched suggestion.  I'm not sure how familiar you are with LESS or LESS compilers, but twitter bootstrap provides their LESS source files.  You could download it and run the bootstrap.less file through a LESS compiler after wrapping the bootstrap file in an ID or class serving as a namespace (I suggest class so you can declare this in multiple locations in your markup).  for example, your bootstrap file could look like the following:

```
.namespace {
    // Core variables and mixins
    @import "variables.less";
    @import "mixins.less";

    // Reset and dependencies
    @import "normalize.less";
    @import "print.less";
    @import "glyphicons.less";

    // Core CSS
    @import "scaffolding.less";
    @import "type.less";
    @import "code.less";
    @import "grid.less";
    @import "tables.less";
    @import "forms.less";
    @import "buttons.less";

    // Components
    @import "component-animations.less";
    @import "dropdowns.less";
    @import "button-groups.less";
    @import "input-groups.less";
    @import "navs.less";
    @import "navbar.less";
    @import "breadcrumbs.less";
    @import "pagination.less";
    @import "pager.less";
    @import "labels.less";
    @import "badges.less";
    @import "jumbotron.less";
    @import "thumbnails.less";
    @import "alerts.less";
    @import "progress-bars.less";
    @import "media.less";
    @import "list-group.less";
    @import "panels.less";
    @import "responsive-embed.less";
    @import "wells.less";
    @import "close.less";

    // Components w/ JavaScript
    @import "modals.less";
    @import "tooltip.less";
    @import "popovers.less";
    @import "carousel.less";

    // Utility classes
    @import "utilities.less";
    @import "responsive-utilities.less";
}
```

Then just make sure that you wrap any bootstrap components in `.namespace` and it should limit the conflicting styles.

This could all fail if any bootstrap components rely on styling the body tag or being inside the body tag, but I don't think that's the case.  It's worth a shot at least.

**edit:** I just remembered something that may cause this whole idea to not work.  Bootstrap relies on adding particular classes on the body tag for modals and the like.  This may also be the case for datepicker.  It all depends on how it lays out, but you can also divide out which styles are in the namespace and which are not.  I would keep the more global ones outside the namespace.

Comment: No classes are required to be added in the body for Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

The datepicker isn't a core component of Bootstrap.  It was a separate jQuery plugin that was popular but used the Bootstrap CSS classes for styling, so it worked well in Bootstrap layouts.

I believe that all you need are the core, utilities, tables, and forms from the Bootstrap CSS files for the datepicker to display properly.  You can of course create your own styles for any of the injected classes or override the base styles so the picker fits with your own site design better.